# Combine two image and save to sd card

Tags: android

I am having code for combining two `image` and show them together in a `canvas`  as follows. Can you say how to `store` that as a `single image`.

```
public class ChoosePictureComposite extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    static final int PICKED_ONE = 0;
    static final int PICKED_TWO = 1;

    boolean onePicked = false;
    boolean twoPicked = false;

    Button choosePicture1, choosePicture2;
    ImageView compositeImageView;

    Bitmap bmp1, bmp2;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        compositeImageView = (ImageView) this
                .findViewById(R.id.CompositeImageView);

        choosePicture1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton1);
        choosePicture2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ChoosePictureButton2);

        choosePicture1.setOnClickListener(this);
        choosePicture2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        int which = -1;

        if (v == choosePicture1) {
            which = PICKED_ONE;
        } else if (v == choosePicture2) {
            which = PICKED_TWO;
        }

        Intent choosePictureIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(choosePictureIntent, which);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();

            if (requestCode == PICKED_ONE) {
                bmp1 = loadBitmap(imageFileUri);
                onePicked = true;
            } else if (requestCode == PICKED_TWO) {
                bmp2 = loadBitmap(imageFileUri);
                twoPicked = true;
            }

            if (onePicked && twoPicked) {
                Bitmap drawingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(),
                        bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
                canvas = new Canvas(drawingBitmap);
                paint = new Paint();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 90, 0, paint);
            //  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(
                    //  android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 30, 40, paint);


                 compositeImageView.setImageBitmap(drawingBitmap);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap loadBitmap(Uri imageFileUri) {
        Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
        float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

        Bitmap returnBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

        try {
            // Load up the image's dimensions not the image itself
            BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

            int heightRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight / dh);
            int widthRatio = (int) Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth / dw);

            Log.v("HEIGHTRATIO", "" + heightRatio);
            Log.v("WIDTHRATIO", "" + widthRatio);

            // If both of the ratios are greater than 1, one of the sides of the
            // image is greater than the screen
            if (heightRatio > 1 && widthRatio > 1) {
                if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                    // Height ratio is larger, scale according to it
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
                } else {
                    // Width ratio is larger, scale according to it
                    bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio;
                }
            }

            // Decode it for real
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            returnBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
        }

        return returnBmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Together` as in? Do you want them side by side? or as overlay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Aura extends Activity {
  protected static final String TAG = Aura.class.getName();
  private static String mTempDir;
  Bitmap mBackImage, mTopImage, mBackground, mInnerImage, mNewSaving;
  Canvas mComboImage;
  FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream;
  BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable;
  private String mCurrent = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aura);

    mTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Aura" + "/";
    mCurrent = "Aura.png";
    prepareDirectory();

    mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(604, 1024, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mBackImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aura);
    mTopImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test);
    mInnerImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anothertest);

    mComboImage = new Canvas(mBackground);
    mComboImage.drawBitmap(mBackImage, 0f, 0f, null);
    mComboImage.drawBitmap(mTopImage, 0f, 0f, null);
    mComboImage.drawBitmap(mInnerImage, 0f, 0f, null);
    mFileOutputStream = null;

    mSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Save Tab Clicked");
        try {
          mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBackground);
          mNewSaving = ((BitmapDrawable) mBitmapDrawable).getBitmap();
          String FtoSave = mTempDir + mCurrent;
          File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
          mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
          mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, mFileOutputStream);
          mFileOutputStream.flush();
          mFileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.v(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.v(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }//onCreate

  private boolean prepareDirectory() {
    try {
      if (makeDirectory()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.sdcard_error), 1000).show();
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean makeDirectory() {
    File mTempFile = new File(mTempDir);
    if (!mTempFile.exists()) {
      mTempFile.mkdirs();
    }

    if (mTempFile.isDirectory()) {
      File[] mFiles = mTempFile.listFiles();
      for (File mEveryFile : mFiles) {
        if (!mEveryFile.delete()) {
          System.out.println(getString(R.string.failed_to_delete) + mEveryFile);
        }
      }
    }
    return (mTempFile.isDirectory());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((!(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT)
        && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)) {
      onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah it worked perfectly.Thanks!! i also wanted to drag one image over the other and place it somewhere and then save. could you help it please..

Comment: You mean you want to put small image on that combine image and then want to save that whole image. .  right ?

Comment: If possible create another answer and put some images as you want to do. Thanks.

Comment: yeah before combining that two images, i wanted to move one image over other and then save it as a single image..i meant so..can u plz help..

Comment: You can use the drag event to move desire image on the perticular image. And then save that canvas in temporary bitmap file. and then use that bitmap as image and do as you like.

Answer (score 0):

create a new `Bitmap` with the height sum of the individual height of your images.

```
        Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widht 
                , totalHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(image11, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(image2, 0, image1Height, null);
```

this should draw the 2 images into the `newBitmap`, one below the other. change height parameters to widht if you want them side by side.

Is this what you were looking for ?

Comment: i also wanted to drag one image over the other and place it somewhere and then save. could you help it please

Comment: consider iDroidExplorer's answer, and apply the same logic to create a bitmap of the combined images.